# How to do Checkout in an Auction style web application with paypal on asp.net website?

Tags: paypal

I'm curious if there is a way to process/connect buyers and sellers on my asp.net site without the site having to charge the buyer and credit the seller. In other words, I don't want to touch the money, but I do want to integrate the process as much as possible on my site.

I guess what I'm asking is how do auction sites manage the transactions between buyer and seller? I really don't want my site to resort to emailing the buyer with the seller's contact information and saying .... "here's the sellers info. Good luck with that."

Ebay seems to allow a buyer to go to PayPal and pay the seller, but returns back to Ebay with payment confirmation. Even though the transaction is between Buyer and Seller, Ebay is able to retrieve some details about that transaction. Is this simply because Ebay owns PayPal, or can other sites do the same?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really about payment processing. You can look into Amazon or Paypal for available APIs beyond the normal buyer <-> seller flow.

e.g.

- [Amazon Flexible Payments](http://aws.amazon.com/fps/)
- [Paypal Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/)

Hth...

p.s. I removed the `ASP.net` tag since this really isn't ASP.Net specific.